# Difference between union() and update() in sets, and others?

Tags: python, set, set-operations

Python sets have these methods:

```
s.union(t)  s | t   new set with elements from both s and t

s.update(t) s |= t  return set s with elements added from t
```

Likewise, there's also these:

```
s.intersection_update(t)    s &= t  return set s keeping only elements also found in t

s.intersection(t)   s & t   new set with elements common to s and t
```

And so on, for all the standard relational algebra operations.

What exactly is the difference here? I see that it says that the update() versions returns s instead of a new set, but if I write `x = s.update(t)`, does that means that `id(x) == id(s)`? Are they references to the same object now?

Why are both sets of methods implemented? It doesn't seem to add any significant functionality.

Comment: Bah, I was reading outdated documentation by accident.

Comment: Where was that? The [2.7.3 sets documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) does not use the language you quote.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html  --which is what comes up when you google "python sets", unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, you found the old [`sets` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html); the `set` built-in *type* was later added to replace that module. At the top it states *Deprecated since version 2.6: The built-in set/frozenset types replace this module.*

Comment: As I have learned today.

Comment: The documentation for that module is actually also incorrect. I checked the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/sets.py) and the `*_update()` methods return None too.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

They are *very* different. One set changes the set *in place*, while the other leaves the original set alone, and returns a *copy* instead.

```
>>> s = {1, 2, 3}
>>> news = s | {4}
>>> s
set([1, 2, 3])
>>> news
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Note how `s` has remained unchanged.

```
>>> s.update({4})
>>> s
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Now I've changed `s` itself. Note also that `.update()` didn't appear to return anything; it did not return `s` to the caller and the Python interpreter did not echo a value.

Methods that change objects in-place never return the original in Python. Their return value is always `None` instead (which is never echoed).

Comment: Ha, 14 months later how this works is so blatantly obvious that it's amazing to me that I had to ask. Thanks though....it's a process.

Comment: Note that `s1.update(s2)` is equivalent to `s1|=s2`. I wonder if there's any performance difference between the two.

Comment: @YiboYang: I ran a `timeit` trial; there is not much difference; `s1|=s2` is fractionally slower (about 1-2% so). Take into account that augmented `|=` assignment does really assign back to `s1` even if that object was first updated in-place (which can have consequences if the target name was a class attribute first, or an element of a immutable object).

Answer (score 2):

The `_update` methods modify the set in-place and return None.  The methods without `update` return a new object.  You almost certainly do not want to do `x = s.update(t)`, since that will set `x` to None.

```
>>> x = set([1, 2])
>>> x.intersection(set([2, 3]))
set([2])
>>> x
set([1, 2])
>>> x.intersection_update(set([2, 3]))
>>> x
set([2])
>>> x = x.intersection_update(set([2, 3]))
>>> print x
None
```

The functionality added by the `_update` methods is the ability to modify existing sets.  If you share a set between multiple objects, you may want to modify the existing set so the other objects sharing it will see the changes.  If you just create a new set, the other objects won't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the docs don't state it in the clearest way possible, but `set.update` doesn't **return** anything at all (which is equivalent to returning `None`), neither does `set.intersection_update`. Like `list.append` or `list.extend` or `dict.update`, they modify the container in place.

```
In [1]: set('abba')
Out[1]: set(['a', 'b'])

In [2]: set('abba').update(set('c'))

In [3]:
```

Edit: actually, [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) don't say what you show in the question. They say:

> Update the set, adding elements from all others.

and

> Update the set, keeping only elements found in it and all others.

Comment: What the OP quotes are not from the [official docs for sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Comment: @Aerovistae 2.7.3 is not outdated, but you were probably reading something other than the official docs.